# Tool Bar back arrow animation using animated vector drawable only working correctly for the first time.

Tags: android, android-animation, android-vectordrawable

I want to change tool bar back arrow to a cross icon with animation. I found some one has already make the necessary vector drawable files in this [git page](https://gist.github.com/stealthcopter/bff831e2bd5e6d09e7ea78e10ade123b#file-vector_back_arrow_to_cross-xml). So I applied it to the back arrow but it only working correctly for the first time. after that it is like setting the last result of the animation and running the animation. refer below gif

[image]

This is my code.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat animDrawable;

        if(firstRun){

            if (!moreDetailFragmentIsHidden) {
                animDrawable = AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(this,
                        R.drawable.vector_back_arrow_to_cross);
                animDrawable.start();
                getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(animDrawable);

            }else{
                animDrawable = AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(this,
                        R.drawable.vector_cross_to_back_arrow);
                animDrawable.start();
                getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(animDrawable);
            }

        }else{
            firstRun = true;
        }

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

on bottom blue bar click i'm calling `invalidateOptionsMenu()`

```
private void onClickBottomMessageContainer() {
        bottomMessageContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (moreDetailFragmentIsHidden) {
                    moreDetailFragmentHolder.startAnimation(revealFromBottom);
                    moreDetailFragmentHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    moreDetailFragmentIsHidden = false;
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                } else {
                    moreDetailFragmentHolder.startAnimation(unRevealFromBottom);
                    moreDetailFragmentHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    moreDetailFragmentIsHidden = true;
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

            }
        });
    }
```